# Python/numpy: Get array locations of a list of values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say I have an array of values `nameArr = ['josh','is','a','person']` and I want a function like `arrayLocation(nameArr,['a','is'])` to return `[2 1]`.

Does that function already exist, if not how can I implement it efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use numpy.where

```
In [17]: nameArr = np.array(['josh','is','a','person'])

In [18]: [np.where(nameArr==i) for i in ['a','is']]
Out[18]: [(array([2]),), (array([1]),)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Lists have a [`index`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) method that you can use.

```
>>> nameArr = ['josh','is','a','person']
>>> # Using map
>>> map(nameArr.index, ['a', 'is'])
[2, 1]
>>> # Using list comprehensions
>>> [nameArr.index(x) for x in ['a', 'is']]
[2, 1]
```

BTW, `index` raises `ValueError` if the element is not in the list. So if you want to supply elements that are not in the list to the index method, you may need to handle the error appropriately.

Comment: Also, it always returns the first index of the item, if the item is in the list multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If the array is large, and do many times of location, you can create a dict that map the value to it's index first:

```
d = dict(zip(nameArr, range(len(nameArr))))
items = ['a','is']
print [d.get(x, None) for x in items]
```

Comment: Given scalability as a measure of quality this is by far the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
>>> f_idxs = np.ravel([np.where(master_data==i)[0] for i in search_list])
```